# PSA: Let's review suggested edits thoroughly

Tags: discussion, psa, suggested-edits

Lately, we have had edits that have, whether intended or not, defaced posts (eg, "Corrected Grammer [sic]" but removed formatting and links or asked some sort of supplemental question different from the original question). Moreover, users from our community have approved these changes, all by anonymous users.

https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10129

https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10128

https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10131

https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10130

https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10123

**PSA: Let's review suggested edits thoroughly**